# Return custom number of bmp images from the same method

Tags: c#, return-value

I want to use a method that returns two or more bmp images, using windows forms in a C# project.

however, the "return image1, image2;" is not a respectful way of doing it.

Which is the fine way to declare that I want to return these two images, and how do I call each one from a function after the declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Just return an array of images.

```
public Bitmap[] GetImages() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your return type Bitmap array `Bitmap[]`

```
public Bitmap[] GetImages()
```

And return it like this:

```
return new Bitmap[] { image1, image2 };
```

Also you can use `List<Bitmap>`

Then you can call it like this:

```
var images = GetImages();

foreach(Bitmap img in images)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<T>`

You didn't post any code, so I am putting some example here.

**To make a method that returns multiple images:**

So instead of:

```
// I am using Image here since I don't know your actual object type and the
// System.Drawing namespace has both an Image class and a Bitmap class
public Image GetImage() { };
```

You'd use:

```
public List<Image> GetImages() { 
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

    ... whatever your code does

    // example pseudo code will probably be a loop, etc.
    images.Add(image1);   
    images.Add(image2);     

    return images;
}
```

You can also use an array.

```
public Image[] GetImages() { ... }
```

**To use them from a function after declaration:** 
(I hope I understand what this means!)

Well there are many ways; you can store them in a local variable in another function, or as a local variable on a class - the answer really depends on what you need them for, when, for how long, etc., generally known as scope... the idea is to store them in the smallest scope possible, so if they're only used in one method call, just declare a local variable there. If other objects interact with these images, then you can store a public List property on a class somewhere, etc.

**Some examples:**

*Local variable inside a method:*

```
public class ImageProcessor
{
    < constructor here, etc. >

    ... 

    public void UseImages()
    {
        List<Image> images = ImageProvider.GetImages();
        images.ForEach(i => [ do something with i ]);
    }
}
```

*Public property on a class*

```
public class ImageContainer
{
    private List<Image> images;
    public List<Image> Images { 
        get {
            if (null == images)
                images = ImageProvider.GetImages();

            return images;
        }
    }

    ... 

    < constructor here, etc. >
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use list:

```
public List<Image> GetImages(int count)
{
    var result = new List<Image>();

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        //create/draw/load your image
        var image = new Image(100, 100);

        result.Add(image);
    }
    return result;
}

static void Main()
{
    var images = GetImages(4);
    foreach(var image in images)
    {
        //do something with image
    }
}
```